# Javascript Pagination Update URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to paginate with Javascript and I'm having trouble updating the URL to ?page={pageNumber}. I'm paginating through 100 items perfectly fine but the URL stays the same and I want to make it seemed as if the page changed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to achieve **domain.com/search/** to **domain.com/search/?page={pageNumber}**

```
    // Adding Page option select menu
    if (document.querySelector("#page-no").innerHTML === "") {
        for (let index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", `${index}`);
            option.textContent = index;

            if (index === 1) {
                option.selected = true;
            }

            document.querySelector("#page-no").appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    document.querySelector(".total").textContent =
        apiResult.data.pagination.total_pages;

    // Add event listeners on pagination items
    document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", prevBtnClick);
    document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", nextBtnClick);
    document.querySelector("#page-no").addEventListener("change", optionSelect);
};

// Event Listener on Previous Button
const prevBtnClick = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
        document.getElementById("page-no").selectedIndex -= 1;
        apiresultFn(animalType, searchLocation, --currentPage);
    }
};

// Event Listener on Next Button
const nextBtnClick = () => {
    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
        document.getElementById("page-no").selectedIndex += 1;
        apiresultFn(animalType, searchLocation, ++currentPage);
    }
};

// Event Listener on Page Menu Change
const optionSelect = (e) => {
    currentPage = parseInt(e.target.value);
    apiresultFn(animalType, searchLocation, currentPage);
};
```

Comment: Your research keyword is _HTML5 History API_ …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add append the query string. Try to use this with your click logic

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?page=2';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```